# Topology and pcf theory

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, cardinal-arithmetic

1. $\DeclareMathOperator\pcf{pcf}$For simplicity say $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit. Let $A=\pcf\{\aleph_n:n\in\omega\}$. Then it follows from basic properties of pcf operation that $X\subseteq A\rightarrow\pcf(X)\subseteq A$, and that pcf is a Kuratowski closure operator on $A$, which gives $A$ a topology. Is $A$ zero-dimensional? Is it compact Hausdorff? I thought I was able to prove that it has finite intersection property for closed sets and hence compact, but [PCF structures of height less than $\omega_3$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20799313) by Er-rhaimini and Velickovic says the pcf space is "locally compact", which confused me a bit. **Edit:** I believe $A$ is compact Hausdorff, and combined with the fact that it's scattered (because if $X\subseteq A$ then $\min X$ is isolated in $X$) we know it's totally disconnected, which for compact Hausdorff space is equivalent to zero-dimensional.
2. The above paper also mentions the pcf space is scattered, and hence one can define a Cantor–Bendixson rank. Is this related to the proof that $\max A<\aleph_{\omega_4}$, say the proof in Jech? If not can the proof be interpreted topologically in any way?
3. This question is probably not so topological, but I hesitate to ask it separately. If $2^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_\omega$, then by pcf theory $\max\pcf\{\aleph_n:n\in\omega\}=\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_{\omega+\omega}^{\aleph_0}=\max\pcf\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n\in\omega\}$. Is it possible to prove $\max\pcf\{\aleph_n:n\in\omega\}\leq\max\pcf\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n\in\omega\}$ directly?

Comment: Please see Section 1.2 of [Some Problems in Singular Cardinals Combinatorics](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-46/issue-3/Some-Problems-in-Singular-Cardinals-Combinatorics/10.1305/ndjfl/1125409329.full). This also would give hints for (2).

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Why is this embedding cofinal?

Comment: It's not clearly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For (1) and (2), you may want to look at Burke and Magidor's [exposition](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82500424.pdf) of pcf theory, as they adopt a topological stance at a couple of places.  For my money, the part of the ``$\aleph_{\omega_4}$ Theorem'' where the topological flavor is strongest is when you prove there is no left-separated subspace of ${\rm pcf}(A)$ of cardinality $|A|^+$.  There are some pieces of the proof that can be phrased in terms of CB rank, but I am not sure how much insight that gives overall. (But that's a matter of taste, I'm sure.)

Regarding (3), you want to be a little careful with your computations, as $2^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_\omega$ does not necessarily imply  that $\aleph_{\omega+\omega}^{\aleph_0}$ is equal to $\max{\rm pcf}(\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n<\omega\})$.

To characterize the cofinality of $([\aleph_{\omega+\omega}]^{\aleph_0},\subseteq)$ in terms of pcf theory, you need to compute $\max{\rm pcf}(\{\aleph_{\alpha+1}:\alpha<\omega+\omega\})$ (using all the infinite regular cardinals less than $\aleph_{\omega+\omega}$) and not just the tail of order-type $\omega$.  If we just look at
$\max{\rm pcf}(\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n<\omega\})$ instead, then we get the cofinality of the structure $([\aleph_{\omega+\omega}]^{\aleph_\omega},\subseteq)$.

From the point of view of general pcf theory, there is a sort of ``inverse monotonicity'' going on in this situation.
If $A$ is an interval of regular cardinals with $|A|<\min(A)$, then ${\rm{pcf}}(A)$ is also an interval of regular cardinals with cardinality less than $|A|^{+4}$. In particular, $\rm{pcf}(A)$ does not have a weakly inaccessible accumulation point and so ${\rm{pcf}}({\rm{pcf}}(A))={\rm{pcf}}(A)$ whenever $A$ is a progressive interval of regular cardinals.

Now let $A = \{\aleph_n:n<\omega\}$.  If $\max\rm{pcf}(A)>\aleph_{\omega+\omega}$ then $\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n<\omega\}$ is contained in $\rm{pcf}(A)$ hence ${\rm{pcf}}(\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n<\omega\})$ is a subset of $\rm{pcf}(A)$.  Thus, in the "interesting" case, pcf theory tells you that

$$\max{\rm{pcf}}(\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n<\omega\})\leq \max{\rm pcf}(\{\aleph_n:n<\omega\}).$$
and therefore if
$$ \aleph_{\omega+\omega}<\max{\rm pcf}\{\aleph_n:n<\omega\}$$
then
$$\max{\rm pcf}(\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n<\omega\})\leq\max{\rm pcf}(\{\aleph_{\alpha+1}:\alpha<\omega+\omega\}=\max{\rm pcf}(\{\aleph_n:n<\omega\}).$$
But in the particular setting you asked about, the above paragraphs are just a fancy way of saying that
$${\rm cf}([\aleph_{\omega+\omega}]^{\aleph_0},\subseteq)={\rm cf}([\aleph_\omega]^{\aleph_0},\subseteq)\cdot {\rm cf}([\aleph_{\omega+\omega}]^{\aleph_\omega},\subseteq),$$
and if $\aleph_{\omega+\omega}<\theta = {\rm cf}([\aleph_\omega]^{\aleph_0})$, then
$$\theta\leq{\rm{cf}}([\aleph_{\omega+\omega}]^{\aleph_0},\subseteq) \leq {\rm cf}([\theta]^{\aleph_0},\subseteq)= {\rm cf}([\aleph_\omega]^{\aleph_0},\subseteq)=\theta.$$

I don't know anything about the value of ${\rm{pp}}(\aleph_{\omega+\omega})$ in various models where ${\rm{pp}}(\aleph_\omega)>\aleph_{\omega+\omega+1}$ (just ignorance on my part), but my assumption is that someone (possibly Gitik or one of his students?) will have analyzed this. I conjecture that it's going to be easier to maintain ${\rm pp}(\aleph_{\omega+\omega})=\aleph_{\omega+\omega+1}<{\rm pp}(\aleph_\omega)$ than it is to blow it up to match ${\rm pp}(\aleph_\omega)$, as this second alternative would involve adding a long scale in $\prod_{n<\omega}\aleph_{\omega+n}$ in addition to the one you need to add in $\prod_{n<\omega}\aleph_n$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction and the detailed answer. So at the end of the day we still need the characterization of maxpcf as the covering number in order to prove (3)? I was hoping that given an ultrafilter $D$ on $\{\aleph_n:n<\omega\}$ we can write down a "concrete" ultrafilter $E$ on $\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n<\omega\}$ that gives the same cofinality, but since $D$ ultimately comes from some Prikry forcing I guess it cannot be made too concrete...

Comment: You can be concrete in the following sense: Suppose  $A=\{\aleph_n:n<\omega\}$ and assume $\theta={\rm max pcf}(A)$ is greater than $\aleph_{\omega+\omega}$.  For each regular $\lambda<\theta$ let $B_\lambda\subseteq A$ be the corresponding generator for $\lambda$.   If we then let $J$ be the ideal on $B=\{\aleph_{\omega+n}:n<\omega\}$ generated by sets of the form $pcf(B_\lambda)\cap B$, then $\prod B / J$ has a increasing and cofinal sequence of length $\lambda$.  Similar arguments let you explicitly write down what the generators for $pcf(B)$ are in terms of the generators from $A$.

Comment: In general, if $pcf(A)$ does not have a weakly inaccessible limit point,  then the pcf structure of any $B\subseteq pcf(A)$ is entirely determined by the pcf structure of $A$ in very explicit way.

Comment: On the other hand, if $pcf(A)$ DOES have a weakly inaccessible accumulation point (something which is not known to be consistent) then the nice correspondence can fail, and there can be $B\subseteq pcf(A)$ for which $pcf(B)$ picks up something new that isn't in pcf(A)$.